# How do I split value of a prop in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a datafield which is date_joined.

```
<h5 className="font-size-15 mt-4">Date Joined</h5>
      <p className="text-muted">
      <i className='bx bx-id-card bx-tada' ></i>
      &nbsp; &nbsp; {this.props.pathologist.date_joined}
     
      </p>
```

This is the code :

```
{this.props.pathologist.date_joined}
returns 2022-08-08T16:53:11.223390Z
```

which is the date&time on which the pathologist was added into the database

now I only want to extract the date from this. so how do I do that

Answer (score 1):

This is returning the date format. You can parse it with the javascript date object. Here is the documetation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

So you can do the following if you want to display the date:

```js
const date = new Date('2022-08-08T16:53:11.223390Z')
console.log(date.toDateString())
```

or in your case you can do

```
<h5 className="font-size-15 mt-4">Date Joined</h5>
  <p className="text-muted">
  <i className='bx bx-id-card bx-tada' ></i>
  &nbsp; &nbsp; {new Date(this.props.pathologist.date_joined).toDateString()}
 
</p>
```

Comment: this is returning me the current date, instead of the date that my prop is returning. e.g 2022-08-08 is what my original backend returns, however this code shows 09-08-2022 on my view

Comment: I added a code snippet above. You can see that it returns Mon Aug 08 2022

Comment: I copy pasted the 2nd code. Tue Aug 09 2022 is what I got, not sure what the issue is though, but I tried another method and it worked for me. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Install the moment library

```
npm install --save moment
```

Import it

```
import moment from "moment";
```

Use it like below

```
{moment(this.props.pathologist.date_joined).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
```

Comment: this is returning me the current date, instead of the date that my prop is returning. e.g 2022-08-08 is what my original backend returns, however this code shows 09-08-2022 on my view

Comment: Then it's --> moment(this.props.pathologist.date_joined).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use date-fns.
[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns)

> your code.

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import { es } from 'date-fns'
// this return the date format 
// "PPP" is the type of format, there are so much depend what do you want
<p>
{format(new Date(this.props.pathologist.date_joined), "PPP",
{locale: es}})}
<p/>
```

different type of format: [enter link description here](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.1/docs/format)